# Customizing react-tradingview-widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tradingview-api

everyone.
I am working on react-tradingview-widget.
I want to add pivot points(only r1~r3, s1~s3) and middle points(m1~m4).
Also, I want to draw green box between each s1 and s2, and red box between each r1 and r2.
This is my code.
I can see r1~r5, s1~s5 but I only want r1~r3, s1~s3, and m1~m4.

```
import React from 'react';
import TradingViewWidget, { Themes } from 'react-tradingview-widget';

const ChartComponent = () => (
  <TradingViewWidget
    symbol="NASDAQ:AAPL"
    theme={Themes.LIGHT}
    studies={[
      "PivotPointsHighLow@tv-basicstudies",
      "PivotPointsStandard@tv-basicstudies",
      "PivotPointsFibonacci@tv-basicstudies"
    ]}
    drawings={[
      {
        "type": "rectangle",
        "overrides": {
          "fillBackground": true,
          "backgroundColor": "#00FF00",
          "transparency": 90
        },
        "points": [
          {
            "time": 0,
            "price": "{{plot_1}}",
            "bar": "{{bar_index}}"
          },
          {
            "time": 0,
            "price": "{{plot_2}}",
            "bar": "{{bar_index}}"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle",
        "overrides": {
          "fillBackground": true,
          "backgroundColor": "#00FF00",
          "transparency": 90
        },
        "points": [
          {
            "time": 0,
            "price": "{{plot_3}}",
            "bar": "{{bar_index}}"
          },
          {
            "time": 0,
            "price": "{{plot_4}}",
            "bar": "{{bar_index}}"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle",
        "overrides": {
          "fillBackground": true,
          "backgroundColor": "#00FF00",
          "transparency": 90
        },
        "points": [
          {
            "time": 0,
            "price": "{{plot_5}}",
            "bar": "{{bar_index}}"
          },
          {
            "time": 0,
            "price": "{{plot_6}}",
            "bar": "{{bar_index}}"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]}
  />
);


export default ChartComponent;
```

I have tried to do it, but I can't customize pivot points and draw boxes.
Please help me.